# Using the %%var%% with batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
CALL SET %PROJECT%_VERSION=1_7_0
echo %%PROJECT%_VERSION%
```

The result will be %PROJECT.

How can I let it to 1_7_0

Comment: `echo !%PROJECT%_VERSION!` or `call echo %%%PROJECT%_VERSION%%`  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 1):

Using `delayedexpansion` makes life easier for these types of scenarios.. You do not need to get the number of `%` 100% either side of the variables and no need to use `call`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "PROJECT=Projectname"
SET "%PROJECT%_VERSION=1_7_0"
echo !%PROJECT%_VERSION!
```